# Why does this Solidity function return a 0 after assert?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I have written this function:

```
// Function to get an owned token's id by referencing the index of the user's owned tokens.
// ex: user has 5 tokens, tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner,3) will give the id of the 4th token.
function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address _owner, uint256 _index) public view returns (uint _tokenId) {
    // TODO: Make sure this works. Does not appear to throw when _index<balanceOf(_owner), which violates
    //       ERC721 compatibility.
    assert(_index<balanceOf(_owner)); // throw if outside range
    return ownedTokenIds[_owner][_index];
}
```

When run with an _index of 2 and an _owner such that balanceOf(_owner) is 0, the function returns a 0 in the Remix IDE. My assumption was that it would not return anything. My questions are:

A) Why does it return a 0 after failing an assert?

B) How do I get this to not return a 0 when I run it with the above parameters?

Thanks,
Vaughn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting my other answer as it was incorrect.

Error handling conditions are not bubbled up to the client in `view` functions. They are only used to revert state changing transactions on the blockchain. For `view` functions, the processing will stop and the initial 0 value of the specified return type is returned (0 for `uint`, false for `bool`, etc).

As a result, error handling for `view` functions has to be handled on the client. If you need to be able to differentiate between a valid 0 return value vs an error, you would do something like this:

```
function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address _owner, uint256 _index) public view returns (uint, bool) {
    bool success = _index < balanceOf(_owner);
    return (ownedTokenIds[_owner][_index], success);
}
```

Comment: If you use this custom definition of `tokenOfOwnerByIndex()` then it would not be compatible with the published ERC-721 standard.